# Run command wirth SSM in Lambda function with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ssm

I wrote python code in lambda for run command from SSM but i had error 
the error

Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "2019-11-26T10:51:09.649Z d6a9aff6-9da9-477c-82b4-100d96a316fe Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}

Request ID:
"d6a9aff6-9da9-477c-82b4-100d96a316fe"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: d6a9aff6-9da9-477c-82b4-100d96a316fe Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: d6a9aff6-9da9-477c-82b4-100d96a316fe
REPORT RequestId: d6a9aff6-9da9-477c-82b4-100d96a316fe  Duration: 3003.16 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 34 MB
2019-11-26T10:51:09.649Z d6a9aff6-9da9-477c-82b4-100d96a316fe Task timed out after 3.00 seconds

the code

```
   from __future__ import print_function

   import json

   import boto3
   import urllib.request

   ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-west-1')
   ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm', region_name='us-west-1')

   client = boto3.client('ssm')
   params={"commands":["mkdir reham1"],"workingDirectory":["/home"],"executionTimeout":["3600"]}
   response = ssm_client.send_command(DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript", InstanceIds="i-0fb28a7b3786adee1",Comment='logging the', TimeoutSeconds=600, Parameters=params)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the timeout setting on your Lambda function is set to 3 seconds, but it takes longer than that for the SSM command to complete (as indicated by the 600 second timeout you have set on the SSM command). You need to increase the timeout on your Lambda function.

Comment: I changed timeout but i have another error 
Response:
{ "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter InstanceIds, value: i-0fb28a7b3786adee1, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'list'>, <class 'tuple'>",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",

Comment: i put InstanceIds in [ ] 
`response = ssm_client.send_command(DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript", InstanceIds=['i-0fb28a7b3786adee1'],Comment='logging the', TimeoutSeconds=600, Parameters=params)`
 and i have that error `response = ssm_client.send_command(DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript", InstanceIds=['i-0fb28a7b3786adee1'],Comment='logging the', TimeoutSeconds=600, Parameters=params)
`